# Toshiba Satellite stays on the screen saying no bootable devices

Tags: hard-drive, boot

A few years ago I upgraded my Toshiba Satellite to Windows10.  It worked for a little while but then I received boot failure.

I have tried a complete recovery and it gets to about 34% before it stops and says it can't do it.  Is this a hard drive failure?  I have actually booted the machine on a USB to Linux mint.

I then tried to install that but that failed. How do I tell if this is a hard drive failure and I need to replace the hard drive?  Is there another OS I can try and install?

Update 07/3/2019
After running the command below here are the results

product: Satellite C55 -B (PSCMLU)
12/11/2014
ZBWAA
/sys/firmware/dmi/tables/smbios_entry_point: Permission denied
/dev/mem: Permission denied

I ran this using an Ubuntu boot stick not Mint (forgot I had changed the stick)  The screen immediately says "disk likely to fail soon".  I tried to attach an image but I could not.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "a complete recovery" what exactly did you attempt?  Healthy, working HDDs, don't cause boot failures.  Unhealthy, failing drives, cause boot failures.

Comment: Boot from a rescue USB drive (e.g. Linux) and save as much of the disk as you can to another drive. Then get a new HDD (or SSD).

Comment: Please run `sudo lshw | grep product | head -n1 && sudo dmidecode -s bios-release-date && sudo dmidecode -s baseboard-product-name && sudo dmidecode -s baseboard-manufacturer` after booting from from yr Mint LiveUSB drive and paste the result into your question after clicking [edit]. Also please put two space characters after each end of line before you press Enter so what you post formats well onscreen.  Please don't click Add Comment as new comments can push old comments off screen; your information about your PC and installation should all go in the Question so we can all see your findings.